# Is this claim right or is there a counter example?

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups

Now let $G$ be a finite topological group. Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then let $(\sigma,V_\sigma)$ be an irreducible representation of $H$. Let $Ind_H^G(\sigma)$ be the induced representation on $G$. More explicitly, the definition here is as below:
[image]
My question is the claim below
$$
\mathbb{C}G\otimes_{\mathbb{C}H}V_\sigma\cong Ind_H^G(\sigma)
$$
How can I find an access to the proof?Looking forward to the sincere help.

Comment: Yes, but the topologies are completely irrelevant. This is sometimes used as the definition of the induced representarion so you'll have to tell us what definition you're using. Also, irreducibility is irrelevant as well.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have added some remarks.

Comment: You can show without too much difficulty that the definition you've given amounts to $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[H]}(\mathbb{C}[G], V)$. To say that this is the same as tensoring with $\mathbb{C}[G]$ just involves showing that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is self-dual as a representation of $H$.